# Custom resolution does not work in vega

Tags: fedora, opensuse, video, resolution, amd-graphics

Im trying to make customs resolutions based on the [xrandr](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-do-i-set-a-custom-resolution), but when trying the relutions via the display utility, it gets a black screen only.
I dont know if this could be a issue of the driver or the video card (since its taking 2 or  GB for vram automatically and whithout the chance of selecting the amount of ram used)

Im using

```
 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso (rev c2)
```

with the module `amdgpu`

Not using ubuntu, but  fedora and suse.